# perform arithmetic operation in two tables using sql

Tags: sql

how can I perform sql query using arithmetic operations and calculate the result

for example:

```
DATEDIFF('2016-10-25', '2016-10-5') AS DiffDate *
   (SELECT package_fee) from table_name
```

the value of package_fee = 10

so the operation is datediff multiply the package_fee

Comment: Your question makes even less sense after I format the code.

Comment: **the constructing of my sentence or question is incorrect

Comment: Do you mean something like `SELECT price * 1.16 AS price_with_tax FROM some_table;`?

Comment: **Nope..actually..I will calculate the day if when did she/he started multiply the package fee or price..for example the package fee is 10

Comment: ** But I got the answer, sir..thanks for the response.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using, DATEDIFF is a product specific function.

Answer (score 2):

I've assumed you wanted the number of days in your date diff as

```
DATEDIFF('2016-10-25', '2016-10-5')
```

is invalid (at least in TSQL):

```
SELECT  package_fee * DATEDIFF(DAY, '2016-10-25', '2016-10-5') AS result
FROM    table_name
```

Comment: Thank you for  responding my question..Im actually a newbie from sql query..I got the answer..Thanks